# General definition for $k$-dependence of a family of sub-$\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

If $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ is a probability space, is there a general definition for the "$k$-dependence" of an ***arbitrary family*** $(\mathcal{F}_i)_{i \in I}$ of sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$ ?

Already know the definition for a sequence and that $k=0$ corresponds to the independence.

How can we define it for an arbitrary family?